# Custom input splits for streaming the data in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a large data set that is ingested into HDFS as sequence files, with the key being the file metadata and value the entire file contents. I am using SequenceFileInputFormat and hence my splits are based on the sequence file sync points.

The issue I am facing is when I ingest really large files, I am basically loading the entire file in memory in the Mapper/Reducer as the value is the entire file content. I am looking for ways to stream the file contents while retaining the Sequence file container. I even thought about writing custom splits but not sure of how I will retain the sequence file container.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The custom split approach is not suitable to this scenario for the following 2 reasons.
   1) Entire file is getting loaded to the Map node because the Map function needs entire file (as value = entire content).  If you split the file, Map function receives only a partial record (value) and it would fail.
2) Probably the sequence file container is treating your file as a 'single record' file. So, it would have only 1 sync point at max, that is after the Header.  So, even if you retain the Sequence File Container's sync points, the whole file gets loaded to the Map node as it being loaded now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the concerns regarding losing the sequence files sync points if writing a custom split. I was thinking of this approach of modifying the Sequence File Input Format/Record Reader to return chunks of the file contents as opposed to the entire file, but return the same key for every chunk.

The chunking strategy would be similar to how file splits are calculated in MapReduce.